# How can I prevent a button from disappearing while selecting a cell of TableView?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4

I have a custom cell in TableView and there is a button in the cell. When I select the cell, the background turns to blue and the button disappears. Is there any way to prevent this?

The cellForRowAtIndexPath like this -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[MyTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}
Search *current = [self.retrievedTweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = current.text;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = current.name;
cell.imageView.image = current.userImage;


btnUncheck =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 35, 20, 20)];


btnUncheck.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
btnUncheck.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
btnUncheck.hidden =NO;
btnUncheck.tag=indexPath.row;
//[btnUncheck addTarget:self action:@selector(didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:btnUncheck];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: 'btnUncheck =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 35, 20, 20)];
    btnUncheck.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    btnUncheck.layer.cornerRadius = 10;          
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnUncheck];'

Answer (score 1):

use custom image for selected table cell. or try with buttons images.

Comment: I tried - btnUncheck.highlighted = NO; and  btnUncheck.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=NO; None working.

Comment: i am asking about selected view of tableview. You can set your own image rather then blue image.

Comment: Yeah !! I did that too. Override the setSelected method .
    
'  (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if ([self.accessoryView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*) self.accessoryView;
        [[button imageView] setHighlighted:NO];
    }
    
}    

'

Comment: cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"listing-gradient-hover.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"listing-gradient.png"]];

Comment: what about the button that I have? Your code removes the blue color, but the button still missing.

Answer (score 0):

paste below line in your tableview Delegate Method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
///// your code ///////////
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
//// your code////////
```

}

here your blue backgound will not display..

Comment: The thing is I want the selection to happen, I have a button in the cell and on the selection I want that to be there.

Comment: just try this code its work but see your cellIdentifier must not nil

Comment: Yes I tried. The code lets the blue color go away, but the button is still not there, does not appear.

Comment: i add checkbox where you add button and it's work fine but i will update new method if its work for this....

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];}
```

Hope this helps

Also, if you have already implemented this, what else do you have in this delegate method?

Comment: Using your code, the blue color appears and then goes away. After that the button appears again. What I need is, the blue color to be there with the button. Which means - the button should be there on selection too. The selection has not to go away.

Comment: What code do you have inside of your disappearing button's target method and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method? Can you post them to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
btnUncheck = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 35, 20, 20)];
```

use:

```
btnUncheck = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
[btnUncheck setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 35, 20, 20)];
```

Comment: If it's possible to share your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, we can help better.

Comment: Hmm. It seems like the button is switching to the highlighted state when the row is selected. Maybe you can use
`- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;`
method for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "custom" view with background color clear and set to it.

```
UIView* vista=[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
vista.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView=vista;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this right, is to create a custom cell that you then add a button to in the xib editor.

So, in xib editor, add a 'UITableViewCell' item.  Then add the button to that cell item in the xib editor.  You'll then attach your custom cell to the table in the corresponding .m file here:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

I have tried this out with just a one row table and the custom cell tied as a property from the xib to the .h file that has the table view.  The highlight is there and just grays out the button (still viewable).  To get this to work with more rows is more involved.  You'll need to load the custom utableviewcell xib and alloc your custom cell dynamically for that to work.